# Viewpager inside Viewpager Scroll Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

in my main activity i have a horizontal viewpager. Inside one of the fragment of the viewpager i have another vertical viewpager. Both works fine. But for the horizontal viewpager, i need to scroll from the edge of the screens. But i want it to be scrolled from anywhere in the screen.

**my horizontal viewpager setup:**

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapterViewPager = new HorizontalViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

**horizontal viewpager adapter:**

```
public class HorizontalViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public HorizontalViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return MoreFragment.newInstance("Fragment MoreFragment", "HA HA HA");
            case 1:
                return NewsFragment.newInstance("Fragment 1", "HA HA HA");
            case 2:
                return WebViewFragment.newInstance("Fragment Webview", "HA HA HA");
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Tab " + position;
    }
}
```

in my news fragment i have another viewpager.

```
viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.shortpager);
        adapterViewPager = new VerticalPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), newsList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
```

**My vertical viewpager class:**

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // The majority of the magic happens here
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
     */
    private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();

        float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
        float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

        ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

        return ev;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
        swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return intercepted;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    }

    private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            if (position <= -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
                // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left/top page
                view.setAlpha(1);
                ViewCompat.setElevation(view, 1);
                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);
                view.setTranslationY(0);

                //set Y position to swipe in from top
                float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
                view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [0,1]
                view.setAlpha(1);
                ViewCompat.setElevation(view, 2);

                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);
                view.setTranslationY(position * view.getHeight());

                // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
                view.setScaleX(1);
                view.setScaleY(1);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**vertical viewpager adapter:**

```
public class VerticalPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
    private final ArrayList<News> newsList;

    public VerticalPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<News> newsList) {
        super(fm);
        this.newsList = newsList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ShortFragment.newInstance("Fragment 1", "HA HA HA", newsList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.newsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Tab " + position;
    }
}
```

Vertical viewpager scrolls smoothly. Currently for horizontal viewpager, i have to scroll from the edge of the screens. But i need to make it scrolled like the vertical one from anywhere in the screen.

Comment: Please how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is your `VerticalViewPager`

If you notice the code,

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
    return intercepted;
}
```

Step-1, Call super with swapped gesture.
Step-2, Perform actions on vertical view pager with current gesture.

And if you specifically see the comment, `// return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views` this clearly tells that gesture is first consumed by child.

So in your vertical view pager since you are swapping the gestures, it is consuming the Horizontal Gesture even before passing it to the parent. Thats why your horizontal view pager do not get the gesture.

If you are using Vertical View Pager with any conflicting gesture implementation like ScrollView, Lists, RecyclerView, ViewPager, etc. use the one as in the link below. It is deprecated but works with all Gesture Conflicting Views.

https://github.com/kaelaela/VerticalViewPager

Comment: i think i have tried with the library you advised. I might have got the same results. Can you tell me how i can fix my VerticalViewPager Class to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I resolved it by wrapping the viewpager in a Scrollview

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </ScrollView>
```